# html5 video player error handling

Tags: html

I have an HTML5 video player that plays mp4 videos (I only have mp4 videos as I'm not a fancy man with fancy multiple codecs). 
I would like to display an error message for when the mp4 videos aren't supported or for when the asset is missing but the whole internet just seems to be people complaining they can't find videos so it's been hard to find a reliable source.

Long story short;
How do I add error messages for when the video is missing or if the codec isn't supported by the browser.

The video code is nice and simple, the source is generated from a server side script and it looks as follows;

```
<video controls height ="500px"> 
    <source src="videos/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support this video player, please consider upgrading to a modern browser or contact your sysadmin.
</video>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How do I add error messages for when the video is missing or if the codec isn't supported by the browser.

Comment: It looks like you already have something to do that.

Comment: That does the trick for old browsers but it doesn't seem to work if the url is busted. I would like a proper error message that tells the user what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you listen for an `error` event on the `<source>` element, it will tell you if loading fails.

```
<source src="videos/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" onerror="alert('Could\'nt load video')">
```

Though you might want to just listen from JavaScript. ;)